# How to do something as soon as Skill is created?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

In my Alexa Skill i set dynamic entities in 'addRequestInterceptors' as the entities must be available as soon as possible, the issue is that if the user says 'Alexa, open `SKILLNAME`' the entities are initialized correctly, but if the user instead says 'Alexa, ask `SKILLNAME` where is `DYNAMICENTITY`' at this point the skill fails as the `DYNAMICENTITY` is not yet set.

So my question is, how can i set my dynamic entities as soon as possible like when the skill is created? I've tryed the LaunchIntent but as in the case above it's avoided if the user make the question inside the invocation..

So LaunchIntent and addRequestInterceptors aren't good to do it..

Here is my code which i should run as soon as possible:

```
const LoadListaPuntiVendita = {
    async process(handlerInput) {
        const {attributesManager, requestEnvelope} = handlerInput;
        const sessionAttributes = attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
        const attributes = await attributesManager.getPersistentAttributes() || {};
        const piva =  attributes.hasOwnProperty('piva') ? attributes.piva : null;
        sessionAttributes["piva"] = piva;
        if (!piva || piva === null) {
            return;
        }
        
        let negozi = sessionAttributes['negozi']
        if (!negozi) {
            const response = await logic.fetchNegozi(piva);
            sessionAttributes['negozi'] = response;
            addDynamicEntities(handlerInput.responseBuilder, 'PuntoVenditaType', response);
            }
        }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possible bug on first glance. This will only run as expected after you've had at least one exchange in which "piva" had been saved and set as a persistent value for the customer.

If you're running this the moment the skill is initialized, it still must be run after the persistence adapter has been initialized and retrieved the value of "piva" from your store AND there must be have been a value stored for "piva" or the code returns early without setting the entity.

Comment: Actually i need to cast a "LoginIntent" if the PIVA is empty but the TEST was made with a PIVA yet stored, but anyway when i invoke the Skill the DynamicEntities are in OUTPUT Json and are set only after another request

Comment: Yes, the dynamic entities are set with the return of the first response from your skill handler in the session and not available until the next utterance. You need to do your own entity resolution from the slot value when they're directly invoking an action intent instead of the launch intent.

Look at this blog post: https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/db4c0ed5-5a05-4037-a3a7-3fe5c29dcb65/use-dynamic-entities-to-create-personalized-voice-experiences and search for "No one-shot support" in the page. As far as I can tell from your question and comment, this is your issue.